# What does a php select prepared statement look like?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Okay.. so ive been looking around on the web for hours now trying to figure out how to convert my old mysql

Here is my php code atm

```
$sql2="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name_question2 WHERE question_id='$question_id_comments' ORDER BY a_id ASC";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
// Comment Loop Starts
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
?>
<div class="row comment-body">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <p><? echo $rows['a_name']; ?></p>
        <span><? echo $rows['a_datetime']; ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <p><? echo $rows['a_answer']; ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } // Comment Loop Ends ?>
```

I have the database connection info already setup properly as I wrote a MySQLi prepared statement to insert content which works, however I cannot figure this one out.

```
$datetime=date("m/d/y h:i"); // Format Date And Time

// Connect
$mysqli = new mysqli('private', 'private', 'private', 'private');

// Check Connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

If someone could show me in the correction direction or show me how to convert this it would be more than appreciated!

**Huge thanks in advance!**

Comment: http://it1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: here you can find a example on select query with bind param http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: See the example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445437/mysql-query-to-mysqli-and-prepare-statement

Comment: Ive read all these and these just seem to really confuse me. I can't figure out how to make it do what I need it to do in the following example in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Prepare the statement, using ? in place of parameters
// Note that you can only use parameters where expressions are allowed, so the
// tablename must still be done by substituting a variable
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT a_name, a_datetime, a_answer FROM $tbl_name_question2
                          WHERE question_id = ?
                          ORDER BY a_id ASC");
// Bind the parameters to the corresponding variables
$stmt->bind_param("s", $question_id_comments);
$stmt->execute();
// Bind variables to receive the results
$stmt->bind_result($name, $datetime, $answer);
// Fetch the rows, and use the above variables to output the results
while ($stmt->fetch() {
    ?>
    <div class="row comment-body">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p><? echo $name; ?></p>
            <span><? echo $datetime; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <p><? echo $answer; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php }
```

Comment: Now this is exactly what I need for this section so thank you sooooo much!!! but curious what if I didnt need to get where question_id = etc what if I just wanted t oget all comments and display them in a while loop how would I write that? Could you maybe include like another block of code underneath ur current showing that? That would be AMAZING!

Comment: If you don't need the `WHERE` clause, just leave it out. Then you don't need to bind a parameter. Otherwise, it's exactly the same.

Comment: So just remove "$stmt->bind_param" and then the "WHERE question_id = ?" ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I said.

Comment: Don't I have to end it as well at the end using "$stmt->close();" and "$mysqli->close();" ?

Comment: I didn't show that part, because I was just showing how to replace the mysql code in your question. If you normally call `mysql_close()`, you can use the equivalent mysqli calls. I don't usually bother, since my scripts always exit shortly after they finish using the database, and that closes everything automatically.

Comment: Ah ic, also in ur code u have while ($stmt->fetch() { ?> in the begining the ( before $stmt never seems to get closed? Is that supposed to be there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54836/discussion-between-kmgilbert100-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

Please check you can use mysqli code for this like example here

```
    <?php
    $mysqli = @new mysqli('private', 'private', 'private', 'private');

    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    /* create a prepared statement */
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name_question2 WHERE question_id=? ORDER BY a_id ASC")) {

    $stmt->bind_param('i',$question_id_comments);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* Store the result (to get properties) */
    $stmt->store_result();

    /* Get the number of rows */
    $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

    /* Get the result */
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>

    <div class="row comment-body">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p><?php echo $row['a_name']; ?></p>
            <span><?php echo $row['a_datetime']; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <p><?php echo $row['a_answer']; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }   

    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
   }

   /* close connection */
   $mysqli->close();
   ?>
```

Comment: Where is the prepared SELECT query that he asked for?

Comment: There is no rule that says you have to use only procedural or OO style. It may be confusing to readers to mix them, and the examples in the documentation are consistent, but I don't think it bothers PHP.

Comment: Now I am really confused

Comment: You're selecting all columns, but you're only binding one result variable, so you'll just get the first column. What about all the other columns?